# Showing a count of associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

As part of my site admin, I need to occasionally update project categories to reflect changing user requirements.

in my `show method` (CategoriesController) , I have the following code:

```
@projects = Project.count.where(:project.category_id => :id)
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class ProjectCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_category
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I can't seem to get it to populate the count of all projects for each category.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the line

```
@projects = Project.count.where(:project.category_id => :id)
```

to

```
@projects = Project.where(:project.category_id => :id).count
```